# C# Manually Sorting Parent/Child tree elements in a list

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, tree, treeview

I am attempting to generate a list of elements that would generate a tree structure if visualized.

**Example:**

```
Element 1 -> 1, 0 //ID is 1 & Parent ID is 0 (0 = root)
Element 2 -> 2, 0 //ID is 2 & Parent ID is 0 (0 = root)
Element 3 -> 3, 1 //ID is 3 & Parent ID is 1
Element 4 -> 4, 3
Element 5 -> 5, 2
```

If a tree is to be visualized with this structure:

[image]

To make this work, here's the Node Class:

```
public class Node
{
    public string id;
    public string parentId;
    public List<Node> children = new List<Node>();  
}
```

> Similar to a tree, a node may contain a parent and it also may contain multiple other
>   children nodes

The task is to sort the elements to their proper hierarchy & add child elements to their respective parent's children collection. There are 2 methods in my mind:

**1) The Loop Method**

i) Loop & find the Base/root nodes (nodes with parent as 0)

ii) Loop & find the nodes with the base nodes as their parent

iii) Add them to the base node's children collection

However the above method is best applicable for a tree of depth 2, meaning the root & their immediate child levels. Imagine a tree with multiple complex levels. This method won't work for that.

That's what I've tried so far.

**2) The 'Recursion' method**

The second method would be the 'Recursion' method. That's what I can't seem to figure out yet. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Has anyone attempted to solve this problem before? How can I arrange a list containing 'n' number of elements with their Parent ID & ID defined?

Comment: I lost point also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a flat `List<Node>` and you want to populate `children` property and end up with a list of the root nodes.

This can be achieved efficiently by building a fast lookup structure by `id` (like `Dictionary`) and single iteration over the source list. For each node you'll find the parent node and add the node to the parent `children` list (or to root list if there is no parent). The time complexity of the algorithm will be O(N).

```
static List<Node> BuildTree(List<Node> nodes)
{
    var nodeMap = nodes.ToDictionary(node => node.id);
    var rootNodes = new List<Node>();
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        Node parent;
        if (nodeMap.TryGetValue(node.parentId, out parent))
            parent.children.Add(node);
        else
            rootNodes.Add(node);
    }
    return rootNodes;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again.  They didn't ask for code.  " How can I arrange a list containing 'n' number of elements with their Parent ID & ID defined"

Comment: This is beautiful! You nailed it. Wow I've been iterating through loops & cursing while playing with 'recursion' & you just gave me that.. *points at the answer*. Thanks man. I would love to learn more about this, can you send me some referral links?

Comment: I checked your answer with a tree that has a depth of 16 levels & it worked like a charm. I appreciate the effort, Ivan

Comment: @DinukaJayasuriya You are welcome, glad it helped:) Unfortunately I can't provide links, I was just improvising :) But I have several posts for tree processing you may find interesting (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5202563+Tree). Cheers.

Comment: @jdweng Well, I did read the whole post, and although you are right that the sentence you are referring to doesn't directly fit with the answer, I believe overall I've answered what I think OP was asking for.

Comment: I think you are assuming the skill level of the OP is higher than what I'm assuming.  It appears the OP doesn't have a lot of experience with recursion.  The looping method he proposed will not work with a 16 deep tree.  I prefer the recursive method than the push/pop method you are using.  I think the recursive is easier to visualize than push/pop.

Comment: @jdweng Well insultations aside, I posted this question because my method didn't work and I wanted to hear other mechanisms :) Ivan's method works for any scenario, so kudos to him. Anyway thanks for trying jdweng

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Thank you for this nice piece of code. I'm a beginner and i don't manage to order childs under their related parent, how would you do this ?

Comment: Hi @Kynao, The simplest is to order the initial list, e.g. `nodes.Sort(…);` or `nodes = nodes.OrderBy(…).ToList();`. Since the tree is built by iterating `nodes`, after running it both `rootNodes` and each `node.children` will be ordered. Another way is to recursively iterate the tree after creation and sort each node children, but to me the first approach is easier.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Stoev. That's what i did at the beginning, then i gave up and added parent.Child = parent.Child.OrderBy(x => x.TargetMarket).ToList(); after parent.Child.Add(node);.  Then i added rootNodes = rootNodes.OrderBy(x => x.TargetMarket).ToList(); This is because i'm on the way to define different values for ordering childs for a given parent, ie it depends of the depth of the parent, so this means all ordering from one parent to another are based on different criterias. Ex: Level 0 : ordering by Lastname, Level 1 : Ordering by FirstName and so on.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev.This is also why i try to integrate here your depth level code but i fail for now

Comment: Hi, @Ivan Stoev,as i need to make this work, can we make a deal to exchange benefits on this?

Comment: Hi @Kynao, There is no need of that, I'll be happy to help as soon as I understand the problem. What is the problem with the second approach I mentioned - recursive sorting after creating the tree. E.g. `static List<Node> Sort(List<Node> nodes, Node parent, int level) { foreach (var node in nodes) { node.children = Sort(node.children, node, level + 1); } return nodes.OrderBy(/* use parent and level */).ToList(); }` and change the last line in the answer to `return Sort(rootNodes, null, 0);`

Comment: Ok,@Ivan Stoev, i try to be more understandable:like you said, we have a flat List<Node> and we want to populate children property and...which your code does. Let's call this result "RESULT1" which is our first element.The second element is an array giving the sorting criterias.Let's say we talk about trucks, array example=["speed", "number of wheels", "number of seats"]. The goal here is to apply sorting by "speed" on all RESULT1 elements at level 0, by "number of wheels" on all RESULT1 elements at level 1, by "number of seats" on all RESULT1 elements at level 2. Hoping to be clearer, am i?:)

Comment: @Kynao Clear. So the recursive `Sort` method I suggested in the previous comment should work, isn't it? You would do inside `if (level) == 0) return nodes.OrderBy(n => n.Speed).ToList(); if (level == 1) return nodes.OrderBy(n => n.NumberOfWheels).ToList(); //etc…`. Btw, you can provide some fiddle link to sample code, then I'll modify it and send you back, etc.

Comment: That would be wonderful,@Ivan Stoev, do you mean https://dotnetfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Kynao Yes. Also let continue our discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180144/room-for-ivan-stoev-and-kynao)

Answer (score -2):

It is usually done like this

```
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
             dt.Columns.Add("parent", typeof(int));

             dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,0});
             dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2,0});
             dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3,1});
             dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4,3});
             dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5,2});
```